# How do I specify the recipient token when using RemoteMessage of Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to establish push notifications in my app for certain actions ("someone liked your this", "someone commented on that" etc).

I tried to follow google's guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)

But when I copied the code, this part of it

```
String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

Gave an error saying it is expecting a `RemoteMessage` and not `Message`.
I am trying to change it to RemoteMessage, but I can't understand:

1. Where do I specify the token of the recipient? I cant find an equivalent to `.setToken`.
2. What to put inside the brackets of `RemoteMessage.Builder()`

I've been going through a lot of manuals but I can't find any that address it. Is it a new change in the API?

The best way to help me would be an example with Kotlin of a new generated message - one that in response would trigger a new push notification for the recipient, based on the token (I'm pretty sure I can handle the receiving by myself).

Thank you!

Edit:

I was able to make it fit the pattern it would be happy with, but I can't get the notifications to show up.

This is the function I am using to send the notification:

```
 fun sendCloudMessage(userId: String) {

        val receiverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$userId/services/firebase-token")

        receiverRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                val registrationToken = p0.getValue(String::class.java)

                Log.d("tokencomplete", p0.toString())
                Log.d("tokenonly", registrationToken)

                val fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()

                fm.send(
                    RemoteMessage.Builder("$registrationToken@gcm.googleapis.com")
                        .setMessageId(Integer.toString(0))
                        .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
                        .addData("my_action", "SAY_HELLO")
                        .build()
                )
            }

        })

    }
```

The `userId` the I pass to this function is the firebase uid, and using that I fetch the most recent token of the app the user is using. I've checked and that part works and I get in return the token in a format similar to this

```
ecK86WRoAh4:APA91bGQWSesCptPF_nzfkmgDe-zOYYo2Cj4XT_NeNTVaBxQakbvauOpkVFd7DCRIugMCfso5SadEUtyTRvrhdCiBpKxGGMRgUYNsUhA24f9IkmxjL5dWD
```

But the function itself doesn't spark any notification in the other device (I am using two devices trying to get one to spark a notification with the other).

Answer (score 0):

Set the sender id in your `RemoteMessage` builder constructor, it  should look like this :

`RemoteMessage.Builder(token)`;

**edit**

here is the method im using :

```
public void sendMessage (final String data) {
FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();

String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
String msgID = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(token + System.currentTimeMillis());
String SENDER_ID = "someID";

RemoteMessage.Builder RMBuilder =
new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com");
RMBuilder.setMessageId(msgID);

Map<String, Object> mapData = Utils.jsonToMap(data);

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : mapData.entrySet()) {
    RMBuilder.addData(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
}

fm.send(RMBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: `builder` is not an option but `Builder` is. The problem is that when I use it I get a different error saying " `expected RemoreMessage but found RemoteMessage.Builder`

Comment: My bad, it says so until I add `build` at the end, though I still can't send it. I am attaching my current code can you please tell me what ti is I am missing? *edit: my browser just refreshed and I saw you've edited your answer, going through it now.

Comment: I've looked at your updated sample, and compared it to mine. I couldn't find a reason why mine wouldn't work. Would you mind taking a look at my edited question please?
 Also, in your answer, I didn't quite get this part `for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : mapData.entrySet()) {
    RMBuilder.addData(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
}`

Comment: OK, so I understand now that sender id is actually my project's id in Firebase which brings me back to my first question : Where do I specify what user this message is intended to?

Comment: no , sender id is the token destination , and the map is data builder